# ESXi - Programming

Tags: vmware

I am looking to run a script which outputs the hardware for a vm solution and I was wondering how to do this.

I have a VC on the solution with multiple hosts and guests.

I am assuming I can do this through the VIX API on the VC server but I don't know.

What I ideally would like is to run a batch file/script which told me how many hosts and then went through the hosts outputting the hardware (such as OS/RAM/CPU etc).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I am aware that this can be done through the VC manually however I would like a script to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to look at VMware's powerCLI which can connect and pull the information for VM's if that is what you're looking for. Below is a cmdlet of powerCLI pulling a VMs hardware information.

```
Get-VM

Name                PowerState   Num CPUs    Memory (MB)
----                ----------   --------    -----------
NW                  PoweredOff      1        512
PowerCLI            PoweredOn       1        1024
```

[VMWare KB](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1028291) this should help